# Text Editor In Adobe Fireworks CS6 has been removed

Tags: cs6, text, adobe-fireworks

I'm using Adobe Fireworks CS6. The latest version
I'm missing a very helpful tool in CS6 is text editor window.
I have also worked on Fireworks CS3 and it has the text editor.

How can I import the text editor from CS3 to CS6?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I import the text editor from CS3 to CS6?

You cant move application specific tools from one version to another.

I would advise checking the documentation from Adobe, [Format and edit text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00db4b-7f89.html).